# Weird! Fatal signal 11 when drawing outside screen bounds

Tags: android, crash, drawing, samsung-mobile, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I get a

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) code=1
```

whenever I draw a filled polygon that crosses the screen bounds. This happens on OS 4.3 on a Samsung Note 10.1. What could cause this? I assume the OS should be able to clip polygons.

The offending code:

```
public SplashStarShape(Context context, int x, int y, int size) {

    super(context);
    paint = new Paint();
    star = new Path();
    star.setFillType(Path.FillType.WINDING);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(DS.scale(10));
    paint.setColor(EslColors.WHITE);
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 360; i += 36) {

        int radius = ((k % 2) == 0) ? size * 2 : size - DS.scale(30);
        k ++;

        float px = (float)x + (float) (Math.cos(0.6 + (float)i * 3.1415926f * 2.0f / (float)360.0f) * (float)(radius/2.0f));
        float py = (float)y + (float) (Math.sin(0.6 + (float)i * 3.1415926f * 2.0f / (float)360.0f) * (float)(radius/2.0f));

        if (i == 0) {
            star.moveTo(px, py);
        } else {
            star.lineTo(px, py);
        }
    }

    star.close();
    this.invalidate();

}

@Override
protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawPath(star, paint);

}
```

If I reduce the radius so that the star fits on screen, there is no crash. If the tentacles stick outside the screen, I get the fatal error. Very strange!

Comment: Also seeing this same behavior on a Galaxy S4. You can go outside of the screen bounds, but there is some limit after which it crashes. Fragmentation problems like these make Android development very challenging.